# PHP Giving links to hashtags and URLs at the same time

Tags: php, function, hashtag

I have a code that converts hashtags to clickable links.

```
function convertAll($str) {
    $regex = "/[@#]([\w\.\-]+)/";
    $hrefs = [
    '#' => 'hashtag?tag',
    '@' => 'users?user'
    ];
    $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
     return sprintf(
         '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
         $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
         $matches[1], 
         $matches[0]
     );
    }, $str);
return($result);
} 
// convertAll(#text) Outputs:
#hashtag (clickable)
'#hashtag' (clickable)
"#hashtag" (clickable)
#hashtag.xxx (clickable)
#hashtag-xxx (clickable)
#hashtag/xxx ("/xxx" not clickable)
#hash tag ("tag" not clickable)
# hashtag (not clickable)
```

This code works good. I don't want to change what it outputs. Besides that, I have another code that makes the URLs clickable and it's working for the same content.

```
$text= preg_replace("@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@", '<a href="$1" target="blank" class="link">$1</a>', $text);
```

This works good too. But the problem occurs when I enter a link with hashtags in it. For example:

```
Input: https://stackoverflow.com/tags#hashtag
Output: #hashtag" target="blank" class="link">https://stackoverflow.com/tags#hashtag
```

`Output should be: https://stackoverflow.com/tags#hashtag`

I don't want "convertAll" function to convert hashtags in the links because it's already converted by the other function. I couldn't figure out how to fix that problem. I would be glad if you help.